# Structure of Laravel App (API, Back office, Front office)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, gulp

### I need help for the structure of my Laravel App.

What I want is basically this structure :

- API
- Admin panel
- Public website

I started to build this folder structure which I think is pretty correct :

```
app/
   Http/Controllers/
       API/
       Back/
       Front/
resources/
   assets/
       js/
          back/
          front/
       sass/
          back/
          front/
   views/
       back/
       front/
```

### Problems

**Elixir**: How can I avoid backend's libraries or assets to be included in frontend's code and vice versa after running `gulp` ?

**Views**: How to use namespaces in Laravel views ? For example, given `pages1` in `views/front/`, which is [extending](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#extending-blade) some `page2`. I want Blade to *automatically* search `page2` inside `views/front` directory when compiling (and not in `views/back` for example).

**Routes**: How to match routes with Controller's namespaces ? I know we can do

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'example.com'], function() {});
```

And also

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {});
```

But how to combine them ?

Comment: Views and routes requirements are not hard to achieve, but I can not understand Exilir requirement

Comment: Simply when I execute `gulp` command, my backend's and frontend's scripts and styles are compiled in 2 files : `app.css` and `app.js`.
I don't want my backend's scripts available from front side... And so, what solution do you suggest for Views and Routes problems ?

Comment: Oh, I see, let me show you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Elixir**, you can use `Gulp` module and then use `mix` variable to separate assets according to your needs. At this example, gulp will merge `script.js` and `script2.js` into a final file named `public/backend/final.js`.

```
// backend assets
elixir(function(mix){
    mix.scripts([
        'js/back/script.js',
        'js/back/script2.js',
    ], 'public/backend/final.js', 'resources/assets');

    // here you can declare another group of assets using 'mix'

});
```

**For controllers namespaces**, you edit `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider` file and declare each namespace as:

```
public function map(Router $router)
{
    // backend namespace
    $router->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\BackEnd'], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes-backend.php');
    });

    // frontend namespace
    $router->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\FrontEnd'], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes-frontend.php');
    });

    // api namespace
    $router->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\API'], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes-api.php');
    });
}
```

Now, create three files:

- **app/Http/routes-backend.php** > Routes for backend
- **app/Http/routes-frontend.php** > Routes for frontend
- **app/Http/routes-api.php** > Routes for API

For example, if you need to declare a new back end controller you detail it at `app/Http/routes-backend.php`:

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@show');
```

Finally **for views**:

> How to use namespaces in Laravel views ? For example, pages1 in views/front/ blade-extending page2 will automatically search page2 inside view/front directory.

That is not possible, there is not way to `page1` autoloads `page2` without an explicit reference. Using `@extends` is enough, and personally I suggest this structure cause you can track your views with very more control.

Comment: **Elixir** : Ok, great. It going to work with my own assets files. But what about bower libraries ? Some libraries I only use from my backend will also be included in my frontend. Any other solution for that, knowing that I use elixir-wiredep to populate my views files ?

Comment: **Views** : I think I'm going to add my front and my back views directories in ´config/view.php´